# How to determine if a PUT request to S3 is creating or overwriting an item?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, put

Using the [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/), I am trying to determine if a PUT request results in the creation of a new object or update of an existing object, without making a second REST API call.

My initial thought was to see if a different status code is returned. Unfortunately I don't see a way to access the HTTP response status code from `PutObjectResult`.

While looking at the SDK docs I found `ObjectMetadata.getLastModified()`. Unfortunately it returns `null` every time I use it.

This is the code I am using to troubleshoot this:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        try {
            PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject("pail", "foo", "first");
            System.out.println(result.getMetadata().getLastModified());
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStatusCode() + " " + e.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

After the first PUT request:

[image: after first PUT]

After the second PUT request:

[image: after second PUT]

For context, I created a bucket specifically for this with default settings and no items.

Any idea why `getLastModified` returns `null` or even how to access HTTP response status codes from `PutObjectResult`?

Comment: You can test if the object exists before upload using doesObjectExist().

Comment: I'm trying to make the distinction without an extra REST API call. In production we're performing ~50,000 PUTs a second from a single cluster. We have more than one cluster. The overhead of one extra call equates to a sizable increase in cost. I'll update the question to include this detail.

Comment: Interesting challenge. I suspect that you cannot get what you want from the PutObject result and will need some other solution. I don't know what you're intending to do for newly-created objects vs. replaced objects so it's hard to propose an efficient alternative.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. At the moment I'm not looking to take different actions but instead understand how many times we overwrite an object. The data itself is immutable so each update is an unnecessary API call/cost. Now that I've been away from the problem for a few hours I wonder if I can get this info from CloudFront.